# How I can get ddl of all objects like table,triggers,procedures etc in Sybase ASE 15.5

Tags: java, database-schema, ddl, sap-ase

I am newbie to sybase and I am using sybase ASE 15.5 on windows 7, I need to extract/generate schema/ddl (tables, stored procedures, views and functions - which I can use to create new database from existing one) from sybase database in java. I have tried following things to get schema -

1. Used Schemaspy.jar file according to it -
   http://marlowa.blogspot.in/2014/02/reverse-engineering-sybase-database.html
   it generate graphical representations of the table/view
   relationships. which doesn't make sense for us
2. I have tried with following command on sybase interactive sql:

   defncopy -Uyouruid -Pyourpwd -Syourserver out out.txt yourdatabase yourtable

   ddlgen -Usa -Shostname:port -D database name -TU -N -o

but both command is not working and giving an error:

> Could not execute Statement Incorrect syntax near 'Usa', Sybase error code = 102, SQLState="42000" Severity level=15, State=1, Transaction State=0

Can you please suggest any command or query to get schema of database

Thanks

Comment: Define "not working". Show the commands and the precise errors.

Comment: Can you please explain what information is missing in this post?

Comment: Hold on, are you trying to execute those from inside `isql`?

Comment: Also, this is nearly identical to the other question you posted.  Please delete one of them.

Comment: Yes I am trying to execute in isql

Comment: Some comments:

1. defncopy and ddlgen are completely separate command line tools from isql - you cannot issue their commands from within isql they are issued on the command line
2. ddlgen comes only with the ASE database binaries and not the open client installation, so if you do not have access to these binaries you'll need a DBA to run the extraction using ddlgen for you